# dotnet pack Release configuration is 3x the size of debug

Tags: .net, .net-core, package, nuget, nuget-package

I have a Razor Class Library that I'm building with static web assets. When I `dotnet pack` locally, in `debug` or `release` configuration, the static files are, as expected, packed in the `staticwebassets` folder and can be exposed in a consuming web app from `_content/{packageid}`:

[image]

However, when I pack it via an Azure DevOps pipeline, I get three versions of the static files in various paths under `content`, `contentFiles` and `staticwebassets`:

[image]

Naturally, this makes the package about three times the size. Here's my command line locally:

`dotnet pack --verbosity Detailed -c Release`

This is what Azure DevOps creates from the classic dotnet pack task:

`dotnet pack {project path}/MyProject.csproj --output /home/vsts/work/1/a --no-build /p:Configuration=Release /p:PackageVersion=18.0.99-CI-20220831-194937 --verbosity Detailed`

This generates hundreds (thousands?) of lines of logging, so I'm not sure where to look to understand the difference. The MSBuild version is the same in both. These appear essentially the same to me, but *something* has to be different.